# Non-algebraic Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups

When trying to learn about Lie groups I find that most natural examples of Lie groups are actually examples of algebraic groups.

What are some interesting examples of Lie groups which are not algebraic groups?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This post was incorrect.  However, as Theo has pointed out, the double cover of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is an example of a Lie group which is non linear and non-abelian, and hence, if it is algebraic, it is at least neither affine nor projective.

The wikipedia page on [Linear algebraic groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebraic_group) has a list of a few criterea which prevent a lie group from being an algebraic group.

Comment: @Theo Buehler Every compact Lie group is linear?  Is there a simple proof?  I feel bad for spreading misinformation.  I wish I remembered who had told me that Spin(n) wasn't linear.

Comment: Well, the precise statement is: a compact group with no small subgroups has a faithful linear representation.  This follows from Peter-Weyl and is von Neumann's solution for Hilbert's fifth problem for compact groups. It's not very hard. However, this doesn't tell you anything about algebraicity.

Comment: The metaplectic group you mentioned before and the universal cover of $Sp_{n}$ would work, too, I guess. But I'm far from my expertise, here.